# How to keep the cell (already with a formula) blank until other cell is populated?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Basically, I have the following formula in the cell which works:

```
=IF(DAY(D9)<=20,"Y",IF(DAY(D9)=DAY(DATE(YEAR(D9),MONTH(D9)+1,0)),"Y","N"))
```

But when the cell `D9` is blank, it keeps showing me the result "Y" in the selected cell. How to keep the above formula in the cell or what to add to the formula to keep the cell blank, until the selected (`D9`) cell is populated?

Many many many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [ISBLANK](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-isblank-function) function:

> =IF(NOT(ISBLANK(D9)), IF(DAY(D9)<=20,"Y",IF(DAY(D9)=DAY(DATE(YEAR(D9),MONTH(D9)+1,0)),"Y","N")), "")

If the column is NOT Blank you can return as empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I needed. :)